# Wordpress redirect of all page/number to home page with .htaccess

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, pagination

I want that all the URL like www.mydomain.com/page/x redirects to www.mydomain.com, when in the place of the x there might be any single number and any combination, how can I do?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

> RewriteEngine On
>    RewriteRule ^/page/$1?$ / [R=301,L]

Answer (score 1):

You can do that with following;

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/page/([0-9]+)$ / [R=301,L]
```